# Split a string in python with spaces and punctuations mark , unicode characters , etc.

Tags: python, regex

I want to split string like this:

```
string = '[[he (∇((comesΦf→chem,'
```

based on spaces, punctuation marks also unicode characters. I mean, what I expect in output is in following mode:

```
out= ['[', '[', 'he',' ', '(','∇' , '(', '(', 'comes','Φ', 'f','→', 'chem',',']
```

I am using

```
re.findall(r"[\w\s\]+|[^\w\s]",String,re.unicode)
```

for this case, but it returned following output:

```
output=['[', '[', 'he',' ', '(', '\xe2', '\x88', '\x87', '(', '(', 'comes\xce', '\xa6', 'f\xe2', '\x86', '\x92', 'chem',',']
```

Please tell me how can i solve this problem.

Comment: `string` does not appear to be a unicode string. Try adding a little `u` before the string literals.

Comment: You won't be able to properly distinguish between "comes", "Φ", and "f" without a lot of effort.

Comment: What's your definition of "letter"? ASCII letter? Because otherwise Ignacio is right. If you allowed unicode letters than you could simply use `itertools.groupby` with a `key` like `str.isalpha`, but this will catch `comesΦf` as a single group.

Answer (score 0):

Without using regexes and assuming words only contain ascii characters:

```
from string import ascii_letters
from itertools import groupby

LETTERS = frozenset(ascii_letters)

def is_alpha(char):
    return char in LETTERS

def split_string(text):
    for key, tokens in groupby(text, key=is_alpha):
        if key: # Found letters, join them and yield a word
            yield ''.join(tokens)
        else:  # not letters, just yield the single tokens
            yield from tokens
```

Example result:

```
In [2]: list(split_string('[[he (∇((comesΦf→chem,'))
Out[2]: ['[', '[', 'he', ' ', '(', '∇', '(', '(', 'comes', 'Φ', 'f', '→', 'chem', ',']
```

If you are using a python version less than 3.3 you can replace `yield from tokens` with:

```
for token in tokens: yield token
```

If you are on python2 keep in mind that `split_string` accepts a *unicode* string.

---

Note that modifying the `is_alpha` function you can define different kinds of grouping. For example if you wanted to considered all *unicode letters* as letters you could do: `is_alpha = str.isalpha` (or `unicode.isalpha` in python2):

```
In [3]: is_alpha = str.isalpha

In [4]: list(split_string('[[he (∇((comesΦf→chem,'))
Out[4]: ['[', '[', 'he', ' ', '(', '∇', '(', '(', 'comesΦf', '→', 'chem', ',']
```

Note the `'comesΦf'` that before was splitted.

Answer (score 0):

Hope i halp.

```
In [33]: string = '[[he (∇((comesΦf→chem,'

In [34]: re.split('\W+', string)
Out[34]: ['', 'he', 'comes', 'f', 'chem', '']
```

Comment: This doesn't work properly. It removes the separators, while they should be kept, and using it with a unicode string you wont be able to split `'comesΦf'` because all these characters are in `\w`.